# python, create a filtered list from a text document

Tags: python

Every time I try to run this program, Python IDLE responds by telling me that it is not responding and has to close. Any suggestions on how to improve this code to make it work the way I want?

```
#open text document
#filter out words in the document by appending to an empty list
#get rid of words that show up more than once
#get rid of words that aren't all lowercase
#get rid of words that end in substring 'xx'
#get rid of words that are less than 5 characters
#print list

fin = open('example.txt')
L = []
for word in fin:
    if len(word) >= 5:
        L.append(word)
    if word != word:
        L.append(word)
    if word[-2:-1] != 'xx':
        L.append(word)
    if word == word.lower():
        L.append(word)
print L
```

Comment: (Also, your logic is way off; you're not getting rid of words that meet one of the criteria; you're keeping one copy of each word for each of your criteria it doesn't break.)

Comment: the text document is VERY large, a few chapters of a book.
and yes, I need a lot of help :(

Comment: I would suggest using re.findall() and make regex like re.compile(' (\w{5})') and so on  :: remove dupes last easily, by casting your list to a set()

Comment: @pyInTheSky:  For 5 *or more* characters the pattern should be `r'\w{5,}'`.  The comma after the 5 opens the range.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski my mistake, misread that in every way, but thanks for the correction

Answer (score 4):

Some general help:

Instead of

```
fin = open('example.txt')
```

You should use

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as fin:
```

then indent the rest of the code, but your version will work.

```
L = []
for word in fin:
```

It doesn't iterate by word, but by *line*. If there is one word per line, each will still have a newline at the end, so you should do

```
word = word.rstrip()
```

to clear any whitespace after the end of the word. If you actually want to do this one word at a time, you need *two* `for` loops, like:

```
for line in fin:
    for word in line.split():
```

and then put the logic inside the inner loop.

```
if len(word) >= 5:
    L.append(word)
```

With stripping the whitespace, that will add any word five letters or longer to the list.

```
if word != word:
    L.append(word)
```

`word` will *always* be equal to word, so this does nothing. If you want to eliminate duplicates, make `L` a `set()` and use `L.add(word)` instead of `L.append(word)` for words you want to add to the list (assuming order doesn't matter).

```
if word[-2:-1] != 'xx':
    L.append(word)
```

If you're trying to see if it ends with `'xx'`, use

```
if not word.endswith('xx'):
```

instead, or `word[-2:]` without the `-1`, otherwise you're just comparing to the next-to-last-letter rather than the whole thing.

```
if word == word.lower():
    L.append(word)
```

This adds the word to the list if the word is all lowercase.

Keep in mind, **all of these `if` tests will be applied to every word**, so you will add the word to the list **once for each test it passes**. If you only want to add it once, you can use `elif` instead of `if` for all the tests except the first one.

Your comments also imply you're somehow "getting rid" of words by adding them to the list -- you're not. You're *keeping* the ones you add to the list, and the rest just go away; you're not changing the file in any way.

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

def by_words(it):
    pat = re.compile('\w+')
    for line in it:
        for word in pat.findall(line):
            yield word

def keepers(it):
     words = set()
     for s in it:
         if len(s)>=5 and s==s.lower() and not s.endswith('xx'):
             words.add(s)
     return list(words)
```

To get 5 words from War and Peace:

```
from urllib import urlopen
source = urlopen('http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2600.txt.utf8')
print keepers(by_words(source))[:5]
```

prints

```
['raining', 'divinely', 'hordes', 'nunnery', 'parallelogram']
```

This does not take much memory.  War and Peace only had 14,361 words that fit your criteria.  The iterators work on very small chunks.

Comment: This is an excellent solution, but you should note that it returns one instance of each word rather than only words that appear exactly once. "get rid of words that show up more than once" is perhaps ambiguous, but your interpretation is different than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I did your homework for you, i was bored.  there might be a bug.

```
homework_a_plus = []
#open text document
with open('example.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for word in fin:
        #get rid of words that show up more than once
        if word in homework_a_plus:
            continue
        #get rid of words that aren't all lowercase
        for c in word:
            if c.isupper():
                continue
        #get rid of words that end in substring 'xx'
        if word[-2:] == 'xx':
            continue
        #get rid of words that are less than 5 characters
        if len(word) < 5:
            continue
        homework_a_plus.append(word)
print homework_a_plus
```

EDIT: like Wooble said, your logic is way off in the code you provided.  Compare your code with mine and I think you will understand why yours has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
words = [inner for outer in [line.split() for line in open('example.txt')] for inner in outer]

for word in words[:]:
    if words.count(word) > 1 or word.lower() != word or word[-2:] == 'xx' or len(word) < 5:
        words.remove(word)
print words
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this before and it didn't do anything, but your method makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write this more as a filter... I would take a slightly different approach.

```
fin = open('example.txt','r')
seenList = []
for line in fin:
    for word in line.split():
        if word in seenList: continue
        if word[-2:] == 'xx': continue
        if word.lower() != word: continue
        if len(word) < 5: continue
        seenList.append(word)
        print word
```

This has the side benefit of showing you each line as it's output. If you want to output to a file instead, modify the `print word` line appropriately, or use shell redirection.

EDIT: If you really don't want to print ANY duplicated words (the above just skips every instance after the first), than something like this works...

```
fin = open('example.txt','r')
seenList = []
for line in fin:
    for word in line.split():
        if word in seenList: 
            seenList.remove(word)
            continue
        if word[-2:] == 'xx': continue
        if word.lower() != word: continue
        if len(word) < 5: continue
        seenList.append(word)

print seenList
```

Comment: Make `seenList` a `defaultdict(int)` and do `seenList[word] += 1`. Current version will print even words that appear more than once. In case OP really wants to show each word (even the repeating ones) once, make `seenList` a `set` and append words without testing whether they are already there.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the easy way with a regex:

```
import re

li = ['bubble', 'iridescent', 'approxx', 'chime',
      'Azerbaidjan', 'moon', 'astronomer', 'glue', 'bird',
      'plan_ary', 'suxx', 'moon', 'iridescent', 'magnitude',
      'Spain', 'through', 'macGregor', 'iridescent', 'ben',
      'glomoxx', 'iridescent', 'orbital']

reg1 = re.compile('(?!\S*?[A-Z_]\S*(?=\Z))'
                 '\w{5,}'
                 '(?<!xx)\Z')

print set(filter(reg1.match,li))

# result:

set(['orbital', 'astronomer', 'magnitude', 'through', 'iridescent', 'chime', 'bubble'])
```

If the data aren't in a list but in a string:

```
ss = '''bubble iridescent approxx chime
Azerbaidjan moon astronomer glue bird
plan_ary suxx moon iridescent magnitude
Spain through macGregor iridescent ben
glomoxx iridescent orbital'''

print set(filter(reg1.match,ss.split()))
```

or

```
reg2 = re.compile('(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=\A))'
                 '(?!\S*?[A-Z_]\S*(?=\s|\Z))'
                 '\w{5,}'
                 '(?<!xx)'
                 '(?=\s|\Z)')

print set(reg2.findall(ss))
```